# Error : cause android.compileSdkVersion is missing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am recently started to work on the Android Studio. When I am doing sync with gradle then it is giving me a error .

> Error : Cause: android.compileSdkVersion is missing!

Guys what could be reason for this, I already have same compileSDKVersion and build tool installed. I see many threads that saying to confirm that you have same sdk version installed in your system but in my case it is already installed.

build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        instrumentTest.setRoot('src/test')
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you insert compileSdkVersion in root/build.gradle or root/HelloWorld/build.gradle ?

Comment: No, it is like this http://pastebin.com/PfXhT2ae If this is required then Android Studio would have added this

Answer (score 14):

I met this problem too, but I don't know whether my solution suit for you. 
I just change the position of this script: `apply from: 'maven_push.gradle'` to the bottom in build.gradle file, and BUILD SUCCESSFUL!

I post my answer here, you can try it.: [Building Android Studio project on Jenkins? android.compileSdkVersion is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041595/building-android-studio-project-on-jenkins-android-compilesdkversion-is-missing)

Answer (score 3):

I did this. It works on Android Studio 0.4.6:

/android_common.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
}
```

/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    classpath 'com.github.jcandksolutions.gradle:android-unit-test:+'
}

allprojects {

    apply plugin: 'idea'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }
}
}

   def langLevel = 1.7

idea {
project {
    jdkName = langLevel
    languageLevel = langLevel
}
  }
```

/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply from: "${rootDir}/android_common.gradle"

android {
defaultConfig {
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    packageName "your.app.package.name"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.+'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.+'
}

sourceSets {
    instrumentTest.setRoot('src/test')
}
}

apply plugin: 'android-unit-test'

dependencies {
instrumentTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
instrumentTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3-SNAPSHOT'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Comment: This answer may need an update. It's for an old version of Android Studio and lists only code and no explaination. I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 3):

If something is missing, and you have clearly declared it, it means that it was queried before it was defined. Move the query (code that requires that variable) somewhere lower, or to a later position in the sequence and it will be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply from: "${rootDir}/android_common.gradle"
```

move your apply from: `"${rootDir}/android_common.gradle"`
to last lines