# android.compileSdkVersion is missing

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, google-play-services

Im using AndroidStudio and Im trying to put some ads on my app, according to the setting up google play API - https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Adter i sync the project with the grandle files i get this error:

```
Error:Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Open in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

This is my gradle.build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pachu.fartsounds"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
}
```

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pachu.fartsounds">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/fart_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".FartActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Any ideas? Thanks !

Comment: Can you post your entire manifest?

Comment: Ok, you're missing critical parts of your manifest.  I'll post an answer down below.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing critical components of your manifest.  The SDK error you are receiving is because the compiler doesn't know at what SDK level to compile your app - you're missing `<uses-sdk`.

And while we're at it, you're also missing your package name, version name, and version code.  These are all critical components to your app.  Here's an example of a well-formed manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.exampleapp"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="v0.2-Alpha" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.exampleapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.example.exampleapp.MyService" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Notice at the very top:  the sections that read `package`, `android:versionCode`, and `android:versionName`.  And also, below those, the entire section that starts with `<uses-sdk`... These are all required.

Comment: Yeah, I know that but when I used eclipse it automaticlly done it for me, but on AndroidStudio it never did so I thought it didnt matter.
But anyways, I changed my Manifest(updated it on the main question also) but I still get the same error : Error:Cause: android.compileSdkVersion is missing.

Comment: Interesting.  Check this question/answer here, and see if anything there is useful, and report back!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343013/error-cause-android-compilesdkversion-is-missing

Comment: I just found out that i got confused between 2 build.gradle files, ill update the question, since now i got a different error

Comment: You don't need to specify the sdk version in the manifest file, if you have it in the module's build.grade file, since gradle generates this into the manifest on build.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
}
```

Comment: does it matter where to add it?

Comment: i see you have problem with com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77, check in folder /path/to/your/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/ the correct version of play services.

The last is 5.2.08 but there is still no update on the play store and I use version 5.0.89

Comment: so just to change it to 5.0.89?

Comment: try to change play services version to 5.0.89, if you get error again try a different version (check inside sdk folder for correct version)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it next way:
in `build.gradle` file of module (usually in *app*, not in root project directory) I set

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        // your application version and id settings
    }
```

where **19** - is and SDK I have completely loaded in *Android SDK Manager*

(same values checked in Studio module settings, *Properties* and *Flavors* tabs).

So, may be your problem is a cause of `minSdkVersion 8` value, when you don't have 8 API installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

In my case the package 'Extras\Google Repository' was not installed.

So after installing it in SDK Manager the problem had gone.