# Build gradle in jenkins failed to find Build Tools revision 21.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, jenkins

I configured `jenkins` on AWS with Ubuntu 14+. I installed sdk, jdk, git, and set ANDROID_HOME. However, I am not able to create avd, and I'm also not able to build with the gradle file:

```
clean -b app/build.gradle
```

Installing sdk:

```
cd /var/lib/jenkins/tools
wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r23.0.2-linux.tgz
tar xvfz android-sdk_r23.0.2-linux.tgz
mv android-sdk-linux android-sdk
```

Checking installation of the SDK:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/tools/android list sdk -a
```

Installing selected SDK:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/tools/android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-21.1.1
```

The error I get:

```
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
failed to find Build Tools revision 21.1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: this Error]

Error show in this picture

## installing sdk

cd /var/lib/jenkins/tools
wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r23.0.2-linux.tgz
tar xvfz android-sdk_r23.0.2-linux.tgz
mv android-sdk-linux android-sdk

## gradle build

clean -b Sports/build.gradle

## update sdk

/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/tools/android update sdk -u -t tool,platform-tool -a

## check sdk installed

/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/tools/android list sdk -a

## install sdk

/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/tools/android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-21.1.1